# How do I fix Electron bluetooth DOMException errors

Tags: bluetooth, electron

I have been working on a bluetooth application with electron. I implemented a custom device picker which works perfectly and I am able to return the `deviceList` as a Promise. When the user clicks a device in the deviceList, I flag and store that device name and ID. I then attempt to connect to the device like so:

```js
const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [
    {
      name: devicesList.deviceName,
      deviceId: devicesList.deviceId,
    },
  ],
});

try {
  const server = await device.gatt.connect();
  console.log('Connected');
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error connecting to Bluetooth device:', error);
}
```

However, I always get the error:

```bash
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: User cancelled the requestDevice() chooser.
```

I am on macOS Sonoma and I have checked to enable bluetooth permissions for electron as other forums have pointed out. I am stuck and have no idea how to proceed. Has anyone had and fixed this issue before or if I'm implementing this all wrong, does anyone have an implementation I can reference?